# Le Potato Board; OSError: libbcm_host: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, package, computer-vision

I am using a Libre Computers LePotato board loaded with Raspbian OS and an arducam multi camera adapter doubleplexer stereo module trying to get a camera feed through the DIO port.

My current issue if I am receiving a command line error rooted in the `picamera` library as follows:
`OSError: libbcm_host: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`
All suggestions are appreciated! Here's my code:

```
import LePotatoPi.GPIO as gp
import time
import numpy as np
import os
import io
import cv2
import picamera
import picamera.array
from PIL import Image

def configureMultiCamera():
    gp.setwarnings(False)
    gp.setmode(gp.BOARD)

    gp.setup(7, gp.OUT)
    gp.setup(11, gp.OUT)
    gp.setup(12, gp.OUT)

    gp.setup(15, gp.OUT)
    gp.setup(16, gp.OUT)
    gp.setup(21, gp.OUT)
    gp.setup(22, gp.OUT)

    gp.output(11, True)
    gp.output(12, True)
    gp.output(15, True)
    gp.output(16, True)
    gp.output(21, True)
    gp.output(22, True)

def enableCamera(num):
    if num == 1:
        gp.output(7, False)
        gp.output(11, False)
        gp.output(12, True)
    elif num == 2:
        gp.output(7, True)
        gp.output(11, False)
        gp.output(12, True)
    elif num == 3:
        gp.output(7, False)
        gp.output(11, True)
        gp.output(12, False)
    elif num == 4:
        gp.output(7, True)
        gp.output(11, True)
        gp.output(12, False)

def disableMultiCamera():
    gp.output(7, False)
    gp.output(11, False)
    gp.output(12, True)

def capture(cam):
    camera.capture('foto-'  + str(cam) + '.jpg')
    
def displayImage(img, mode):
    """
    Displays the four images
    """
    if not len(img) <= 0 and mode == 1:
        height, width, z = img[0].shape
        if len(img) < 4:
            for i in xrange(4 - len(img), 4):
                img.append(np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8))
        #identifying the images
        cv2.putText(img[0], 'Cam 1', (5, 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .4, 255)
        cv2.putText(img[1], 'Cam 2', (5, 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .4, 255)
        cv2.putText(img[2], 'Cam 3', (5, 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .4, 255)
        cv2.putText(img[3], 'Cam 4', (5, 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .4, 255)
        #Combines the images into one to display
        image = np.zeros((2 * height, 2 * width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        image[0:height, 0:width, :] = img[0]
        image[height:, 0:width, :] = img[2]
        image[0:height, width:, :] = img[1]
        image[height:, width:, :] = img[3]
        # Display
        cv2.imshow('Multi-Camera Raspberry Pi by Maik', image)
    if mode == 2:
        for i in xrange(0, len(img)):
            cv2.imshow('Camera ' + str(i+1), img[i])
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numberOfCameras = int(input("Number of cameras:"))
    configureMultiCamera()
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        
        #camera settings
        camera.resolution = [160,112]
        camera.framerate = 30
        
        #time to wait for the settings to be applied successfully
        time.sleep(2)
        
        #create all camera streams
        stream = list()
        for i in xrange(1,numberOfCameras+1):
            stream.append(io.BytesIO())
            
        while True:
            
            startTime = time.time()
            
            img = list()
            
            for i in xrange(1,numberOfCameras+1):
                enableCamera(i)
                camera.capture(stream[i-1], format='jpeg')
                data = np.fromstring(stream[i-1].getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8)
                #Decode the image from the array, preserving colour
                image = cv2.imdecode(data, 1)
                #get the array of the image
                img.append(image.copy())
                #Delete the contents of a stream.
                stream[i-1].seek(0)
            
            #Display all images
            displayImage(img, 1)
            #displayImage(img, 2)
            
            totalTime = time.time() - startTime
            print("Aquisition time:"+(totalTime)+"s")
            print("FPS(all cameras):"+(1 / totalTime))
            
            # If we press ESC then break out of the loop
            key = cv2.waitKey(7) % 0x100
            if key == 27:
                break
            
    disableMultiCamera()
    #Clears the cash at the end of the application
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```